# ActiveMQ ConnectionFailedException

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I am trying to post a message to ActiveMQ using JMS,

```
String loginID="admin";
String loginPswd="admin";
String hostName="svful0000283np.nyzdc.local";
String channel="http";
String portNumber="8161";
String hostUrl=channel + "://" + hostName + ":" + portNumber;
String inputQueue="com.nbn.telecom.sap.ManageSQ";
String outputQueue="com.nbn.telecom.sap.ManageSQ.response";

String messageText="my text";                              
ConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(loginID, loginPswd,hostUrl);         
Connection connection = factory.createConnection();   
Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
```

Last statement in the above gives the below error message -

```
   org.apache.activemq.ConnectionFailedException: The JMS connection has failed:            Failed to perform GET on: http://svful0000283np.nyzdc.local:8161 Reason: null
```

What could be the reason for the error? Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While grasping your Question again, I am seeing **`8161`** port... it is **jetty default port**..... that provision ***ActiveMQ Admin Console*** for its Administration.....

You could only use its messaging ports for messaging..... Port **61616, 5672, 61613, 1883, 61614** for **openwire, amqp, stomp, mqtt, ws protocol** messaging respectively.....

That config resides right here.... on '[ACTIVEMQ_HOME]/**conf/activemq.xml**'

```
          <transportConnectors>
                <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
                <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
                <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
                <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
                <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
                <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
          </transportConnectors>
```

You could change port to some other number if it doesn't conflicts....

0.0.0.0 works only for loopback ip 127.0.0.1... I mean only at localhost....

Else replace ip 0.0.0.0 by finding ip by `ifconfig` if it is unix..... else `ipconfig` if it is Windows or DOS based... that should be done on the machine where you are running ActiveMQ

Comment: Mostly this exception occurs, could be because of firewall issue.... or because of other network related issues..... And I hope you run ActiveMQ in different machine.... Else also as you are using `hostname` for your connection..... you need to update you `/etc/hosts` even for a local machine.... That's the issue then it say,- not able to resolve host.